# How to build a heatmap?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, heatmap

I want to build a heatmap where on Y-axis will be number of trees, on X number of leafs, and in the center auc-roc
Here is my code

```
df = pd.DataFrame(store,columns = ['n_trees' , 'n_leafs', 'auc-roc']) 
df.set_index(['n_trees'], inplace=True)
ax = sns.heatmap(df)
```

My dataframe looks like this:

```
         n_leafs   auc-roc
n_trees                   
10             1  0.7
10             3  0.892529
10             5  0.107495
159            1  0.155
159            3  0.7581
...          ...       ...
1202           3  0.420
1202           5  0.422
1351           1  0.398
1351           3  0.273
1351           5  0.795
```

and I get this heatmap, not something I wanted. How to delete auc-roc on X-axis and transfer it to the center?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pivot your data into a long format, using an example dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(111)
df = pd.DataFrame({'n_trees':np.repeat([10,159,1202,1305],3),
                  'n_leafs':[1,3,5]*4,
                   'auc-roc':np.random.uniform(0,1,12)})
```

Pivot will make it like this:

```
df.pivot(index="n_trees",columns="n_leafs")
```

[image]

We can pivot and plot:

```
sns.heatmap(df.pivot(index="n_trees",columns="n_leafs"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Reset the index via `reset_index` and then use `pivot` to transform the table.

```
df = df.reset_index()
ax = sns.heatmap(df.pivot(*df), annot=True)
```

[image]